# Disable view interaction during visibility transition

Tags: android, android-transitions

I'm adding layout animations to my apps using the `Transition` API and I was naively anticipated that this framework - like any properly designed layout animation engine built on top of existing non-animated layout engine - would implement "as if" behavior, i.e. adding animation should not break existing "non-animated" behavior. Particularly, views which visibility is set to GONE/INVISIBLE should already be non-interactive during transition. Unfortunately, looks like it's not the case with the `Transition` API: views being animated out retain focus and can be clicked [again] during animation, breaking the internal logic of an Activity/Fragment.

So, I wonder: is this by design or am I missing something? Can it be fixed without disrupting animated view's properties and/or resorting to special "interaction-blocking" wrapper views?